# Gostaria de digitar no edit e os valores das letras aparecerem noTMemo utlizando esse formato de função

Tags: delphi-7, lazarus

Eu ficaria muito grata se pudesse me ajudar!

Ele só dá o valor da letra digitada no edit se eu teclar uma só 
vez, se eu tentar duas ou mais dá erro, gostaria de saber no
 que estou errando, gostaria de mostrar o valor da letra 
repetidamente conforme digitar ela no edit.

```
digitaria no teclado: zAAAAAB zzzz
no Edit exibiria: 5111111 5555

function m (x:string):string;
   var y:string;
   z,w:integer;
   begin
   if(x='A') or (x ='a') or (x='Â') or (x='â') or (x='ã') then y :='1';
   if(x='b') then y:='1';
   if(x='c') then y:='1';
   if(x='z') then y:='5';
  ......

Result:='';
for w:=1 to Length(x) do
begin
z:=0;
repeat z:=z+1;
until x[z]=x[z];
Result:=Result+y[w];
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
memo1.text:=(m(edit1.text));
end;
```

Comment: Acho que a variável z e o looping com o repeat/until são desnecessários e se você reparar a variável z não está sendo utilizada para montar o result.

Comment: E os Ifs para atribuir um valor para a variável y devem ficar dentro do looping for/do para avaliar cada caractere da string x e para isso deve ser utilizada a variável w como indice. A variável y deve ser utilizada sem índice já que vai possuir sempre um único caractere. Considere ainda acrescentar código para attibuir algum valor para a variável y quando o caractere avaliado for diferente de todos os que estão previstos.

Comment: oi Imex, obrigada pelas suas dicas, nossa, eu estou tendo bastante trabalho e dificuldade  para montar essa função sozinha eu iniciei nos estudos de programação a pouco tempo, ainda sou aprendiz, eu programava em html, você poderia me ajudar se for muito incomodo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão de código para estudos e testes:

```
function m(x:string): string;
var
  y: string;
  w: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for w := 1 to Length(x) do
    begin
      if (x[w] = 'A') or 
         (x[w] = 'a') or 
         (x[w] = 'Â') or 
         (x[w] = 'â') or 
         (x[w] = 'ã') or
         (x[w] = 'b') or
         (x[w] = 'c') then
        y := '1'
      else
        if x[w] = 'z' then 
          y := '5'
        else
          y := ' ';
      Result := Result + y;
    end;
end;
```

O looping For/Do é utilizado para acessar cada caractere da string separadamente, e dentro do looping é utilizada uma sequencia de Ifs para atribuir um valor para a variável y conforme o valor desse caractere, e em seguida o valor da variável y é concatenado para formação do resultado retornado pela função.

Espero que ajude

Comment: Oi imex! 
Ajuda sim, que legal era isso mesmo que estava precisando, muito obrigada, muito feliz, Deus lhe pague.

Comment: Que bom que a resposta ajudou. Avalie por gentileza a possibilidade de aceita-la como uma resposta.

Comment: Ajudou muito sim, muito obrigada, aceito sim como resposta, tá respondida e resolvido, muito obrigada, att.